# TextBox mascara de valor de 2 até 4 casas decimais em WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Gostaria que meu TextBox tivesse a seguinte "mascara"
Quando eu colocar duas casas depois da virgula:

> 0,00

ou quando eu colocar três:

> 0,000

ou quando eu colocar 4:

> 0,0000

Meu código no WPF C# e o seguinte:

```
 <TextBox  x:Name="ValorProdutoTextBox"  
  Text="{Binding ValorProduto, NotifyOnValidationError=true,
  ValidatesOnExceptions=true,  ConverterCulture='pt-BR'}"
  UpdateSourceTrigger="ValorLostFocus"
   Height="20"
   Width="100" Margin="1" />
```

O resultado esta vindo sempre como determinado pelo 'Binding ValorProduto' que está no banco de dados (DECIMAL 15,4)

> 0,0000

Comment: Você tentou  adicionar um `StringFormat=N2` no seu binding?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo o n2 somente vai duas casa decimais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue o exemplo do código:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=N2}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0:#,#.00}}" />
```

Resposta original: [StackOverFlow Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362876/6647038)